# wp7 Application transitions

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, transition

In one of my wp7.1 app, i am trying to use the Transition to enhance the look and feel of the app. To do so, i am using Silverlight toolkit November release.

however after enabling the transitions the performance of the app has gone down(i have seen this point mentioned in other posts as well). the problem seems to be in loading the new page. A blank screen appears between loading pages, which does not look good.
 Here is my implementation, i am defining the style in app.xaml

```
  <Style x:Key="Transition" TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationPage">
      <Setter Property="toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition">
          <Setter.Value>
              <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
                  <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
                      <toolkit:SlideTransition Mode="SlideRightFadeIn"/>
                  </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
                  <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
                      <toolkit:SlideTransition Mode="SlideLeftFadeIn"/>
                  </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
              </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
          </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Setter Property="toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition">
          <Setter.Value>
              <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
                  <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
                      <toolkit:SlideTransition Mode="SlideRightFadeOut"/>
                   </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
                   <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
                      <toolkit:SlideTransition Mode="SlideLeftFadeOut"/>
                   </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
              </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
          </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
  </Style>
```

Then in each page i am defining the

```
Style="{StaticResource Transition}
```

In app.xaml.cs i have defined the root frame as

```
RootFrame = new TransitionFrame
{
    Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent)
};
```

Any solutions to optimize the transitions or solve the problem of Blank screen coming between two pages

Comment: Can anyone provide me some insight over this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not set on using the Silverlight toolkit, you could use the open source WP7 Contrib transitions. In my experience, they perform better than the toolkit.

http://wp7contrib.codeplex.com/

I abandoned the toolkit due to issues like this.